# Validar que el numero de cuenta no se repita

Tags: c++, array

¿Cómo valido que el numero de cuenta no se haya utilizado anteriormente?.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int n = 3;
int numero_cuenta[3];
int pin[3];


int main(){

        int indice=0;
        int menu=0;
        bool centinela=true;
        bool random=true;
        int cuenta=0;
        int pin_C=0;

do{
        cout << endl;
        while(random){
            cuenta = rand()%100+100000;
            cout << " El numero de cuenta es:" << cuenta << endl;
            Sleep(4000);
            numero_cuenta[indice] = cuenta;
            random = false;
        }
        system("CLS");
        cout << " Generando numero de PIN. ";
        cout << endl;

        random = true;

        while(random){
        pin_C = rand()%30+1000;
        cout << " El numero de PIN es:" << pin_C << endl;
        pin[indice] = pin_C;
        random = false;
        }

        indice++;
        Sleep(1500);
        if(indice <=n){
        cout << endl;
        cout << " Desea Ingresar otro cliente? Espacios usados " << indice << " Si(1) No(2): ";
        cin >> menu;
        random=true;

        system("CLS");
        }

        if(indice==n){
            cout << endl;
            cout << " Limite de espacios alcanzados." << endl;
            menu = 2;
        }

        if(menu==2){
            /*system("CLS");
            cout << "Nombre: " << nombre_C[0] << " ";
            cout << " " << apellido_C[0] << endl;
            cout << "Telefono: " << ". " << telefono_C[0] << endl;
            cout << "Correo: " << correo_C[0] << endl;
            cout << "Numero de Cuenta: " << numero_cuenta[0] << endl;
            cout << "Pin: " << pin[0] << endl;
            */
                centinela=false;
            }
        } // Fin del Do
        while(centinela);

} // Fin del main
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar [`std::set`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). Este contenedor no admite duplicados por lo que es facil verificar si ya contiene un número dado:

```
std::set<int> numeros;

while(random)
{
  cuenta = rand()%100+100000;
  bool ok;
  std::tie(std::ignore, ok) = numeros.insert(cuenta);
  if( !ok )
    std::cout << "Numero repetido";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres asegurar que algo que ya has usado no se repita, usa algun estructura de datos. Una facil de comprender seria un map que llames visitado. Revisa si lo has visto chequeando el otro dato. Hay varias otras como un set donde puedes chequear si lo has visto usando find y si resulta ya ha estado agregado.

Espero que eso te sirva!